# Use process name generated by supervisord in child process logging

Tags: python, logging, supervisord

I want to use name of child process (like "mysuperservice_1", "mysuperservice_2", etc...) in child process logging. Services built with python.

How can I do it? TIA! =)

**EDIT1**

my supervisord config looks like:

```
[program:superservice]
command = python manage.py superservice
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)s
autostart=true
autorestart=true
numprocs=4
stdout_logfile=spool/logs/superservice.log
stderr_logfile=spool/logs/superservice.error.log
```

it will produce process like that:

```
dizpers   4912  0.3  0.5 170472 21976 ?        Sl   22:09   0:00 python manage.py superservice
dizpers   4913  0.3  0.5 170476 22520 ?        Sl   22:09   0:00 python manage.py superservice
dizpers   4920  0.2  0.5 170476 22524 ?        Sl   22:09   0:00 python manage.py superservice
dizpers   4926  0.3  0.5 170476 22432 ?        Sl   22:09   0:00 python manage.py superservice
```

So, I can't just simply get process name (by **psutil** module, for example). I need somehow get it through supervisord.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're not using `multiprocessing`, then the process name will normally always be `MainProcess`. To override this, you can add a filter to the appropriate handlers which works something like this:

```
import os, logging
class SupervisorProcessFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        record.processName = os.environ['SUPERVISOR_PROCESS_NAME']
        return True
```

and then use `%(processName)` in the format string, as Hai Vu suggests.

Comment: thx! `os.environ['SUPERVISOR_PROCESS_NAME']` is exactly what I need! I missed this from supervisord docs

Answer (score 2):

In the main code, you configure the logging format with `%(processName)`, for example:

```
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format='[%(levelname)s] (%(processName)s) %(message)s')
```

Then, in the child process:

```
logging.debug('About to do XYZ')
```

The output:

```
[DEBUG] (mysuperservice_1) About to do XYZ
```

Comment: You are wrong. Using your method I will get "MainProcess" as process name. Using for example psutil module (and get process name by pid) I will get simply "python". Its so cause of all services just `python myservice.py ...`.

Comment: This is part of my working code. I am using the `multiprocessing` module. psutil is not even mentioned in the original posting.

Comment: Hai Vu, I've updated original post. Thx for notice =)